# Why is a blank page being displayed when I call my servlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm currently trying to complete a simple Web project using Activiti. I doing it in Eclipse using a Tomcat 7.0 server. I have a servlet that should display a tasks info but even if there's a problem there surely it should still display something.

I'm only starting to learn JSP so I apologise for any stupid mistakes I may have made in the code.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome.</h1>
    <br />
    <h3>Go to:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="loanrequest.jsp">Request Loan</a></li>
        <li><a href="ManagementTasks">Management Tasks</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine;
import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines;
import org.activiti.engine.TaskService;
import org.activiti.engine.task.Task;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ManagementTasks
 */
@WebServlet("/ManagementTasks")
public class ManagementTasks extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ManagementTasks() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><head><title>Management Tasks</title</head><body>");

        ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();

        TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
        List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery()
                .taskCandidateGroup("management").list();

        if (tasks.size() > 0) {

            out.println("<h1>You have " + tasks.size() + " task(s) to complete.</h1>");

            Task t = tasks.get(0);

            out.println("<br /><br /><h2>" + t.getDescription() + "</h2>");
            out.println("<br />Do you want to approve this request?</h2><br />");
            out.println("<form method=\"POST\" action=\"ManagementApproval\">");
            out.println("<label for=\"approve\">Do you approve?</label>");
            out.println("<select name=\"approve\">");
            out.println("<option value=\"true\">Yes</option>");
            out.println("<option value=\"false\">No</option>");
            out.println("</select><br />");
            out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"taskId\" name=\"taskId\" " + "value=\"" + t.getId() + "\" /><br/>");
            out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit Form\" />");
            out.println("<input type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset Form\" />");
            out.println("</form>");


        } else {

            out.println("<h1>There are no tasks for you. </h1>");

        }

        out.println("<a href=\"index.html\"> HOME </a>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the doGet method and doing a "Debug on Server" to see what's going on?

Comment: Have you seen the URL you're navigating?

Comment: Is it possible there's an exception happening? You could put everything after the `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();` in a try-block and dump any caught exceptions to `out`, then call `out.close()` in the `finally`.

Comment: @stvcisco or even better: forward to a JSP instead of writing the HTML directly from servlet.

Comment: You are following the links there and not posting with a form right? Because you do have an empty post method.....

Comment: Is it okay to link to the servlet the way I did in the index.html? I'm gonna change the servlet to pass on the attributes I need to a .jsp page.

Comment: I've got it working now. Just forwarded the attributes I needed to a .jsp. I feel kind silly now. Thanks.